# How do I read or fetch emails from a distribution list using JavaMail API?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3, distribution-list

I have a distribution list which receives emails from several sources and broadcasts the same to set of users.

This distribution list has its own identity `abc@xyz.com` without any credentials so that I cannot access it anywhere.

How do I read or fetch emails received on this distribution list using POP3 or IMAP? Does JavaMail support such operation?

Comment: Add an archiving mailbox to the distribution list?

Comment: Exactly.  Create an account, add it to the distribution list, then read the emails delivered to that account.